# Dynamics AX 2009 Database Diagram

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009

i'm desperately searching for dynamics ax 2009 database diagram. 
Does anyone have it ?

Thank you

Comment: Been looking for that for a year myself. I wish the tables used foreign keys. That would make my life so much easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Me too.  Let us know if you find anything because I don't think it exists...  In the meanwhile try this unfinished [AX40datamodel.doc](http://kashperuk.net/DynamicsAX/AX40datamodel.doc) document to kick-start your knowledge.

Comment: Link is sadly dead

Answer (score 8):

For a list of tables in AX 2009 see the MSDN documentation [Dynamics AX 2009 Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc652476%28v=AX.50%29.aspx)

To create a Visio UML Data Model diagram, place the tables you want to include in a project and use the [Reverse Engineering Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa552178%28v=AX.50%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

With more than 2000 tables it would be a huge diagram.
If you look at the tables in the AOT most of them have relations set on them
You can also use the Cross-Reference
Select the table / table field you are interested in knowing more about.
Right click / Add-Ins / Cross-Reference / Used by
Here you will get a complete list of everywhere the selected object is used

The Cross reference must be updated ofcourse - prior to this.
It can be a long process - most the time it is only updated in Development and Test environments

You do that by clicking the main AOT node. Right click here and do like mentioned above. But select 'Update' instead of 'Used By'. It may take hours